# Memory leak in Pytorch: object detection

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, memory-leaks, pytorch

I am working on the [object detection tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html#putting-everything-together) on PyTorch. The original tutorial works fine with the few epochs given. I expanded it to large epochs and encounter **out of memory** error.

I tried to debug it and find something interesting. This is the tool I am using:

```
def debug_gpu():
    # Debug out of memory bugs.
    tensor_list = []
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        try:
            if torch.is_tensor(obj) or (hasattr(obj, 'data') and torch.is_tensor(obj.data)):
                tensor_list.append(obj)
        except:
            pass
    print(f'Count of tensors = {len(tensor_list)}.')
```

And I used it to monitor the memory of training one epoch:

```
def train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq):
    ...
    for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, print_freq, header):
        # inference + backward + optimization
        debug_gpu()
```

The output is something like this:

```
Count of tensors = 414.
Count of tensors = 419.
Count of tensors = 424.
Count of tensors = 429.
Count of tensors = 434.
Count of tensors = 439.
Count of tensors = 439.
Count of tensors = 444.
Count of tensors = 449.
Count of tensors = 449.
Count of tensors = 454.
```

As you can see, the count of tensors tracked by garbage collector increases constantly.

Relevant files to execute can be found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/references/detection).

I have two questions:
1. What is holding up the garbage collector to release these tensors?
2. What should I do with the out of memory error?

Comment: Are you doing it in several threads? I found an issue where seemingly intact tensors (I do only inference) are copied for each thread upon access, consuming more and more memory.

Comment: @ViacheslavShalamov I did it in a single thread. If possible, would you please tell me what the tensor is or how did you locate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How I identify the error?
   With the help of [tracemalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html), I take two snapshots with several hundred iterations between. The tutorial will show you it easy to follow.
2. What cause the error?
   `rpn.anchor_generator._cache` in the Pytorch is a python `dict` which trace the grid anchors. It is an attribute with the detection model and the size increases with each proposal.
3. How to solve it?
   An easy bypass is put `model.rpn.anchor_generator._cache.clear()` at the end of training iterations.

---

I have submit a [fix](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/1657) to PyTorch. You may won't have the OOM error since torchvision 0.5.